# Using Random Number Generator for a Loop Timeout

Tags: javascript, loops, random, timeout

This script should scroll through each container on a website with a randomly generated delay.
I want to replace the "pause" of `2000`ms with a randomly generated number between `min` and `max` seconds for each iteration in the loop.

```
var min = 3,
    max = 9;
var y = document.querySelectorAll('.chunk-container').length;

for (let x=0; x<y; x++) {
   task(x);
}

function task(x) {
//    var z = randomGen() * 1000;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('X = ' + x + ' Y = ' + y);
            document.getElementsByClassName('chunk chunk-container')[x].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
            console.log('Scrolled to next Container');
    }, /* z */ 2000 * x);
}
})
```

Random number generator:

```
function randomGen() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    console.log('Random Number generated: ' + rand + ' seconds');
    return rand;
}
```

Like this it works fine. After each iteration, there is a 2 second pause. However when I remove the comments to add the lines `var z = randomGen() * 1000;` to randomize the time between each iteration, the `x` value (at which container it should scroll to) starts off fine, but then turns out random as well.

The console output:

```
Random Number generated: 6 seconds
Random Number generated: 5 seconds
Random Number generated: 4 seconds
Random Number generated: 8 seconds
Random Number generated: 4 seconds
Random Number generated: 8 seconds
X = 0 Y = 7
Scrolled to next Container
X = 1 Y = 7
Scrolled to next Container
X = 2 Y = 7
Scrolled to next Container
X = 4 Y = 7
Scrolled to next Container
X = 3 Y = 7
Scrolled to next Container
X = 5 Y = 7
Scrolled to next Container
X = 6 Y = 7
Scrolled to next Container
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I guess you would like them to start one after another, and not with all timeouts at the same time as it currently does? Sorry, I might have overread it in your question.

Comment: @OskarGrosser Well the funny thing is, each iteration actually uses the timeout that gets generated. So when `X = 0` the timeout was actually 6 seconds etc. Although sometimes, even that was not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote you code.
I think the main problem was that `setTimeout` is non blocking.
I used `promise` together with `await` to solve it

```
function sleep(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function randomGen(max, min) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

async function randomWaitAndScroll(elements, timeMin, timeMax) {
  for (element of elements) {
    let random = randomGen(timeMin, timeMax)
    await sleep(random);
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
}

const containerElements = document.querySelectorAll('.chunk-container');
randomWaitAndScroll(containerElements, 3000, 9000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `2000 * x` works because the delay between each scroll is constant, so your timeouts trigger at:

- `x = 0` -> 0ms
- `x = 1` -> 2000ms
- `x = 2` -> 4000ms

So you launch *all of the timeouts* at once at the start and they end up triggering every 2 seconds, but each timeout's value is different. Each implicitly depends on the fact that all timeouts before have been triggering every 2 seconds.

One approach would be to use an asynchronous function that returns a promise and `await` for it before scrolling to the next element as [Josh points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65908507/8364541)

An alternative would be to keep track of the previous timeouts values and add them up, to compute the next timeout's value. Like this:

```
var min = 3,
    max = 9;
var y = document.querySelectorAll('.chunk-container').length;

for (let x=0, accumulatedDelay = 0; x<y; x++) {
    accumulatedDelay += task(x, accumulatedDelay);
}

function task(x, accumulatedDelay) {
    const z = randomGen() * 1000;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('X = ' + x + ' Y = ' + y);
            document.getElementsByClassName('chunk chunk-container')[x].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
            console.log('Scrolled to next Container');
    }, z + accumulatedDelay);

    return accumulatedDelay;
}
```